# Define onClick param not in xml file android

Tags: java, android

I start with android and I have a problem. I have buttons which are created dynamically with this code :

```
for (User u: Users) {        
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    linearlayout.addView(layout);
    Button username = new Button(this);
    username.setText(u.getUsername());
    layout.addView(username);
    }
```

And I want to set an `onClick` function to my button but I don't know how to do this not in a xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to set an onClick function to my button but I don't know how to
>   do this not in a xml file

Add click listener to Button by calling `setOnClickListener` as:

```
for (User u: Users) {        
    ....
     Button username = new Button(this); 
     username.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View view) {
          // Perform action on click   
       }
     });
     ....
    }
```

Comment: @SimonM.: setOnClickListener method is already available but you need to set it to Button by passing View.OnClickListener instance to get onclick callback

Comment: The thing is I'm not able to create a new Intent inside `onClick` method. Any idea ?

Comment: @SimonM.: Depend on how you are creating it do it as `Intent intent=new Intent(view.getContext(),NextActivity.class);`